# pandas - plotting lines and markers with different zorders?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot scattered lines and markers from a `pandas` dataframe, however in certain situations the lines end up being drawn on top of the markers. Is there any way to set the `zorder` of the lines and markers separately to ensure the marker is always drawn on top of any line, regardless of series? e.g. something like `marker_zorder=2, line_zorder=1`

For example, the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 5, 10],
                   'y1': [24, 7, 14],
                   'y2': [14, 6, 35]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 5))
df.plot.line(x='x', ls='--', marker='.', ms=15, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
plt.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Produces this graph:

[image: Graph with overlapping markers and lines]

Where we can see the orange line is drawn over the blue marker.

Comment: One heck would be to plot scatterplot on top of line plot that imposes themselves on markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as `marker_zorder`. But you may plot your data twice, once as a line and once with markers on top.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 5, 10],
                   'y1': [24, 7, 14],
                   'y2': [14, 6, 35]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 5))
df.plot.line(x='x', ls='--', ax=ax)

# Reset prop cycle to obtain the same colors for the next plot
ax._get_lines.set_prop_cycle(plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"])
df.plot.line(x='x', ls='', marker='.', ms=15, ax=ax, legend=False)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm. This does the trick, but that legend is nasty. I assume `ax._get_lines.set_prop_cycle(plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"])` is just setting the same colour cycle for the lines and markers?